# Is there a simple way of sending hits server-side directly to Google Analytics in .NET?

Tags: .net, google-analytics, server-side, tracking, measurement-protocol

In my organization, we have built a module for our Drupal sites, that tracks hits server-side directly to Google Analytics via the Measurement Protocol API. The Module is dependent on [theiconic Google Analytics Measurement Protocol library for PHP](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol).

We are looking to create something similar for .NET, but I have not had any luck with finding a library for this other than [Google Analytics SDK for .NET](https://github.com/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk). Does anyone have experience with using this library for .NET server-side tracking or know of a different one, that will do the job?

The beauty of our PHP module is the simplicity and ease of using the library to track specific events. Additionally this was relatively simple and fast for our developer to set up.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is no official SDK for .net for sending hits to Google analytics.  The closest thing you will find is [google-analytics-dotnet-sdk](https://github.com/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk) which works server sided and was created using .net standard..  As lead developer on the project I'm happy to address any questions you may have with the library.   I have used it on several projects there is one currently running recording several million hits a day.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. That sounds promising. How does it handle stitching client-side and server-side information? Will it be possible to connect these so hits are stored in sessions, instead of registering it as a new user every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: The SDK supports all the normal session parameters in the measurement protocol if you have the season data you can easily send it along with your request.  From what i can see in the PHP library you have posted they appear to work in the same way in that respect.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I will look further into this option.

Comment: if you have any issues you are welcome to post them here on stack, the github project or email me again 

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. :)